# How can I listen to sound files on my android wear device with ff/rw and saving song position capabilities?

Tags: music-player, android-wear

I have a moto 360 sport. I currently have used Play Music to listen to songs when my phone is not connected to the watch. This app is missing two huge features that I need.

1. I cannot fast forward or rewind a track by single tapping, double tapping, or long pressing the forward/back buttons on my headphones. Not to be confused with skipping to the next or previous track.
2. I cannot turn the headphones off, go to a meeting, come back, and resume the song where I left off.

Is there a way to have the ability to do these two things, while not connected to the phone?

I have tried WearMedia. This one almost makes the cut, but I cannot fast forward or rewind the track with the buttons on my headphones or pause/play with headphone buttons and had limited success with controlling the finger drag ff/rw on the screen.

I have also tried podcast addict and some similar apps. These have the right player features, but are missing the offline/phone disconnected ability.

I'm open to the idea of modifying an open source app with a starting music player feature but cannot find one.